# Problema con una declaración de array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

ando haciendo una practica de php y me sale imprimidoen pantalla el siguiente error **Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aprendizaje_PHP\datos_servidor_blob\leer_archivo_bbdd.php on line 38
ID: Tipo:**

```
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="widht=device-width, user-
    scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximun-scale=1, minimun-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

    $ID="";
    $Contenido="";
    $Tipo="";

require("conexion.php");

$db_conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);

if ( mysqli_connect_errno()){

    echo "Fallo al conectar con la bbdd.";

    exit();
}

mysqli_select_db($db_conexion,$db_nombre) or die ("No se encuentra la bbdd.");
mysqli_set_charset($db_conexion, "utf8");

$query="SELECT * FFROM ARCHIVOS WHERE ID=3";

$resultado=mysqli_query($db_conexion, $query);

while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){

    $ID=$fila["ID"];

    $Contenido=$fila["Contenido"];

    $Tipo=$fila["Tipo"];



}

    echo "ID: " . $ID;

    echo "Tipo: " . $Tipo;

    echo $Contenido;
?>




</body>

</html>
```

Y los datos de la bbdd son los siguientes:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El objetivo de esta practica, es mostrar el archivo seleccionado en la pregunta, y que se muestre en pantalla, sin decodificar del campo blob, que es donde estoy atascado. Y mas adelante decodificando el campo blob.

Comment: Amigo yo quiza me esté equivocando sintacticamente hablando, pero es un error que no puedo aclarar en google, ya que copiar y pegar el expects 1 parametrer de un array a vez funciona mejor que lo vean mas ojos, en cambio no se si preguntar que una etiqueta <a> de html se tenga que preguntar si lleva un atributo href por obligación, eso es algo que se prueba y ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error en tu consulta, estas escribiendo, FFROM cuando deberia ser de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT * FROM archivos WHERE ID=3
```

Checalo bro, dime si funciona

Comment: Esa fue, muchas gracias compañero!! en 4 minutos pondre te pongo el tick de validez que esto fue lo que me sirvio muchas gracias!!!.

Comment: Correcto, después de una consulta tienes que preguntar si en realidad trajo algo, la construcción típica es `$resultado = mysqli_query(...) or die('ocurrió un error ' . mysqli_error(...);`

Comment: Esta clase de preguntas no se contesta.. se aclara en un comentario y listo... no son relevantes para futuras busquedas...

Answer (score 0):

El mysql_fetch_array, consta de dos parametros, en tu parte....

```
$fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)
```

Esta haciednofalta la variable de conexion, entons quedaria asi....

```
$fila=mysqli_fetch_array($db_conexion, $resultado)
```

Con eso ya dberia de darte, sino me equivoque en la variable que esta realizando la conexion